# How to change pygtk gtk.Button color PROPERLY

Tags: python, user-interface, button, colors, pygtk

In my application, I have about 500 buttons which all update their labels and colors when specific actions are taken. I was running into crashes and performance issues when I noticed (by using cProfile and pdb) that the problem was caused by changing the button color:

```
self.button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_PRELIGHT, color)
self.button.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)
```

500 calls like this need an eternity of 5 seconds (which also freezes GUI) and it gets even slower the longer the application runs. In case someone wonders, I have a powerful processor and lots of free memory.

Previously I was trying to use EventBox as recommended in the [docs](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=edit&file=faq04.016.htp). However this only changes the color behind the button, not on its surface:

```
import gtk

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

btn = gtk.Button("test")
eb = gtk.EventBox()
eb.add(btn)
eb.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse("red"))

win.add(eb)
win.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

Result:

[image: button is not red]

I also tried the alternative which involves retrieving and modifying the the style. This led to the same slowness as with `modify_bg`. In addition I also got random crashes at random places, usually with low level memory allocation errors such as double freeing from gtk.

```
import gtk

win = gtk.Window()
win.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)

btn = gtk.Button("test")
#copy the current style and replace the background
style = btn.get_style().copy()
style.bg[gtk.STATE_NORMAL] = gtk.gdk.color_parse("red")

#set the button's style to the one you created
btn.set_style(style)

win.add(btn)
win.show_all()

gtk.main()
```

It seems that the color of the button is managed by the operating system and I can't find a way around it without slowness, crashes or undesired results. I badly need to convey by color important information about the button.

So how do I change the button color properly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own Button by using a `gtk.EventBox` which holds a `gtk.Label` inside of its widget tree. Unlike with buttons, setting label color seems not to conflict with the operating system.

I also implemented a couple of convenience functions such as `set_label()`

`modify_bg` is still too slow, but it doesn't lead to crashes. By checking if current color is the same as the one I want to set, I also saved a lot of computation time for buttons that don't change.

My code is very sketchy but it works for my purposes. Feel free to make it more robust and/or flexible:

[image: my colored button]

```
import gtk

class ColoredButton(gtk.EventBox):
    '''
    This class implements a simple unanimated button 
    whose color can be changed
    '''

    def __init__(self, widget = gtk.Label()):
        '''
        widget must be a gtk.Label
        this is not checked in this simple version
        '''

        #initialize superclass EventBox
        super(ColoredButton, self).__init__()

        #embed widget inside vbox and hbox 
        self.widget = widget 
        self.vbox = gtk.VBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0) 
        self.hbox = gtk.HBox(homogeneous=False, spacing=0)
        self.hbox.pack_start(self.vbox, expand = True, fill=False)
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.widget, expand = True, fill = False)

        #draws a frame around the entire construct to make everything look more like a button
        self.frame = gtk.Frame()
        self.frame.add(self.hbox)

        #add the final "button" to this EventBox in order to handle events
        self.add(self.frame)

        #define which events should be reacted to, those constants can be found in pygtk docs
        self.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK)
        self.add_events(gtk.gdk.BUTTON_PRESS_MASK)
        self.add_events(gtk.gdk.ENTER_NOTIFY_MASK)
        self.add_events(gtk.gdk.LEAVE_NOTIFY_MASK)

        #activate focus
        self.set_can_focus(True)

        #align the "button" text in the middle of the box
        self.widget.set_alignment(xalign=0.5, yalign=0.5)

    def show(self):
        super(ColoredButton, self).show()
        self.hbox.show()
        self.vbox.show()
        self.frame.show()
        self.widget.show()

    def set_label(self, label):
        self.set_text(label)

    def set_text(self, text):
        self.widget.set_text(text)

    def changeColor(self, color, state = gtk.STATE_NORMAL):
        if color is not None:
            currentcolor = self.style.bg[state]
            #too lazy to look up in docs if color != currentcolor also works
            if color.red != currentcolor.red or color.green != currentcolor.green or color.blue != currentcolor.blue:
                self.modify_bg(state, color)

    def changeTextColor(self, color, state = gtk.STATE_NORMAL):   
        if color is not None:
            currentcolor = self.style.bg[state]
            if color.red != currentcolor.red or color.green != currentcolor.green or color.blue != currentcolor.blue:
                self.widget.modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, color)

def onButtonClick(widget, event = None):
    if event.button == 1:
        widget.set_label("left click")
    elif event.button == 2:
        widget.set_label("middle click")
    elif event.button == 3:
        widget.set_label("right click")

import gtk

w = gtk.Window()
w.connect('destroy', gtk.main_quit)

coloredbutton=ColoredButton(widget = gtk.Label("Hello there"))
coloredbutton.changeColor(gtk.gdk.color_parse("black"))
coloredbutton.changeTextColor(gtk.gdk.color_parse("yellow"))
coloredbutton.set_size_request(width = 100, height = 50)
coloredbutton.connect("button-release-event", onButtonClick)

w.add(coloredbutton)

w.show_all()
gtk.main()
```